# Jquery $.get using selenium python

Tags: jquery, python, selenium

I was trying make a jquery get request using selenium python from the web page but I am always getting None as the response. Here is the code.

```
    from selenium import webdriver
    from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
    import time

    driver = webdriver.PhantomJS()
    driver.get(url)
    time.sleep(5)
    driver.execute_script("ok = $.get("+get_url+")") #get_url same domain as url 
    print driver.execute_script("return ok.responseText")
    driver.close()
```

Please tell me what is going wrong here. Also please tell me any other alternatives for doing this if this is not possible with selenium python.

Comment: Can you not do it all in the same script? `return $.get("+get_url+").responseText"`

Comment: Yes I can but I am again getting none again.

Comment: Consider using https://pypi.python.org/pypi/selenium-requests/

Comment: can it request another url from a url. If yes please help me with a sample code by answering the question.

Answer (score 1):

`$.get` is asynchronous.

You can do a promise with the `$.get` and in a success (or failed), you can create a DOM element with the answer and with Selenium you can use a WebDriverWait, for wait for that element with the response.